# Don't understand why my line keeps on getting replaced in ansible using lineinfile

Tags: deployment, informix, ansible

This is my `group_vars`:

```
services:
  service_csmsaga:
    service_name: "service_csmsaga"
    port: "21100/tcp"
  service_csmsagatcp:
    service_name: "service_csmsagatcp"
    port: "21200/tcp"
```

I want to add these lines into my `/etc/services` using:

```
- name: Add saga services to /etc/services
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/services regexp='^{{ item.value.service_name }}'
              line="{{ item.value.service_name}}    {{ item.value.port }}"
  with_dict: services
```

The lines have already been added to `/etc/services` like below:

```
service_csmsaga    21100/tcp
service_csmsaga    21100/tcp
service_csmsaga    21100/tcp
service_csmsagatcp    21200/tcp
```

but it still keeps on adding the line:

```
TASK [db_server : Add saga services to /etc/services] **************************
changed: [172.17.0.2] => (item={'value': {u'service_name': u'service_csmsaga', u'port': u'21100/tcp'}, 'key': u'service_csmsaga'}) => {"backup": "", "changed": true, "item": {"key": "service_csmsaga", "value": {"port": "21100/tcp", "service_name": "service_csmsaga"}}, "msg": "line replaced"}
changed: [172.17.0.2] => (item={'value': {u'service_name': u'service_csmsagatcp', u'port': u'21200/tcp'}, 'key': u'service_csmsagatcp'}) => {"backup": "", "changed": true, "item": {"key": "service_csmsagatcp", "value": {"port": "21200/tcp", "service_name": "service_csmsagatcp"}}, "msg": "line added"}
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your `regexp` parameter and then your data.

The first iteration (`service_csmsaga`) will match both lines so will replace both lines with the first one. Then the second iteration will add a new line to the end because `service_csmsagatcp` doesn't exist. Then when you run your playbook again your first iteration replaces all three lines and so on and so forth.

To fix it you need to either change your data (change the name of the service) or be more specific in your regex.

Something like this should work:

```
- name: Add saga services to /etc/services
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/services regexp='^{{ item.value.service_name }}\s'
              line="{{ item.value.service_name}}    {{ item.value.port }}"
  with_dict: services
```

This will then make sure it only matches the `service_name` followed by some whitespace before replacing it so that your service names don't overlap.